# USB accessories test error in CTS Verifier.. Version 6.0_R6

Tags: linux, cts

I am trying to run USB accessories test case in CTS Verifier using version 6.0R6 and it fails with as the sent and received message for Host PC and DUT dose not match.
and error shown as "**USB_Device_open Failed**" , 
                   "**Failed to start accessories mode**" and "**Failed to read protocol version**"

**Points :**

1.Same host pc works fine with earlier version of CTS verifier like 5.x

2.The USB accessories version has been changed from previous one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it worked by making change in rules file by giving permission to Group .. 0600 and executing case as ./cts-usb-accessory in place of sudo ./cts-usb-accessory

Thanks